# How to bind both the option's value and text in a drop down list using Angular.JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In Angular.JS, is there a way to bind two different ng-models when a select drop down option is selected?

Angular code:

```
<select ng-model="vm.data.styleId" ng-options="item.id as item.name for item in vm.getStylesData.styles">
    <option value="">Select a Style</option>
</select>
```

Results in:

```
<option value="{{item.id}}">{{item.name}}</option>
```

With the Angular code I have so far, when an option is selected, it will save the option's value to the ng-model. In this case `item.id` is bound to `vm.data.styleId`.

However in addition to this, I also need to bind the 'item.name' of the selected option. Basically, when an option is selected, I need to bind both the `item.id` to `vm.data.styleId`, and the `item.name` to `vm.data.name`.

Is there an easy way to do this using Angular.JS?

---

**Solution** (using the answer from lisa p.):

In the View:

```
<select ng-model="vm.styleItem" ng-change="vm.getDetails()" ng-options="item as item.name for item in vm.getStylesData.styles">
    <option value="">Select a Style</option>
</select>
```

Inside the controller:

```
vm.getDetails = function () {
    // set the values of the select drop down
    vm.data.styleId = vm.styleItem.id; 
    vm.data.style = vm.styleItem.name;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can bind to an object containing both values like

```
item = { styleId: 23, name: "the name" }
vm.data = {{ styleId: ..., name: ... }}
```

then you bind to vm.data with

```
<option value="{{item}}">{{item.name}}</option>
```

Comment: Thank you. That worked perfectly for what I needed. Cheers!

Comment: Glad to help. Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

**Controller**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {

    $scope.vm.data.styleId = "";

    $scope.item = {id : '1', name : 'name'};    

});
```

**html**

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
 <select ng-model="vm.data.styleId" ng-options="item.id as item.name for item in vm.getStylesData.styles">
    <option value="{{item}}">{{item.name}}</option>
</select>

</div>
```

Make an object which holds both id and name and pass that object as value to option